# Change the content of a Div while typing an input

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I need to change the content of multiple DIVs while typing an input.

I have been able to change the first div, tried to use some loops and browsed different other questions here without success.

```js
let input = document.getElementById('in');
let out = document.getElementById('out');

input.onkeyup = function() {
  out.innerHTML = input.value;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="in">
<div id="out"></div>
```

I should display the value from input #in to a several div #out (they will be classes).
Whitout using JQuery.

Comment: Post your attempt at doing this and you will get more responses.

Comment: Your posted code only has one DIV. What are the other DIVs you want to update?

Comment: You should be able to update all of them the same way. What problem are you actually having?

Comment: Thanks, I found the solution today and checking the ones posted by others. My mistake was on selecting the DIVs in a wrong way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with `document.getElementsByClassName("out");` and then use a for loop to change all the different elements.
In the for loop you can access the element by `elems.item(index)`.

See the snippet below:

```js
let input = document.getElementById('in');
let outs = document.getElementsByClassName("out");

input.onkeyup = function() {
  for(var i = 0; i < outs.length; i++){
      outs.item(i).innerHTML = input.value;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="in">
<div class="out"></div>
<div class="out"></div>
```

Comment: This is really useful and works great! I want to modify it a little, so I have a question: If adding default text to the input field like `value="Sample text"` and I want the page to load with that text first, then continue to listen for key input... what's a good way to do that?

Comment: P.S. Technically I got it working, but my code is ugly and redundant. I've got the function defined twice, once for each triggering event.

Answer (score 0):

make your divs with `out` class and use `document.querySelectorAll` to get all elements with query selector

```js
const input = document.getElementById('in');
const divs = document.querySelectorAll('.out');

input.onkeyup = function() {
  divs.forEach(function(div) {
    div.innerHTML = input.value;
  });
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="in">
<div class="out"></div>
<div class="out"></div>
<div class="out"></div>
<div class="out"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried so far? The issue I see right away is just that you are grabbing a single element for out instead of multiple elements.

```
<script>
    let input = document.getElementById('in');
    let out = document.getElementsByClassName('out');

    input.onkeyup = function () {
        for each (let item in out) {
            //loops through each element with the class 'out' and sets the innerHTML to the input's value
            item.innerHTML = input.value;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for the help, I found the solution this morning anyway:

```
<input type="text" id="sentence">
    <div class="out"></div>
    <div class="out"></div>

    let input = document.getElementById('sentence');
    let divs = document.querySelectorAll('div);

    input.addEventListener('keyup', function(){
          for(let i=0; i < divs.length; i++){
              divs[i].innerHTML = input.value;
          }
    })
```

Checking the other answers I am wondering about the differences between:

```
divs.forEach(function(div){ ... })

for each (let item in out) { ... }

for(var i = 0; i < outs.length; i++){ ... }
```